# All applications that uses the Internet permission

Tags: java, android, permissions

I have this code to get all applications that uses the Internet permission, but something is wrong, help me please :)

```
public String[] getAppsWithNet() {

    int flag = 0;
    String[] appsNet = new String[50];
    PackageManager p = c.getPackageManager();
    final List<PackageInfo> apps = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    for (PackageInfo pkg : apps) {
        for (String permission : pkg.requestedPermissions) {
            if (p.PERMISSION_GRANTED == p.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET, pkg.packageName)) {
                appsNet[flag] = pkg.packageName;
                flag++;
            }
        }
    }
    return appsNet;
}
```

thank in advance...

Comment: In log cat I have java.lang.NullPointerException, and I don't understand why...

Comment: in which line? can you post the log cat?

Comment: In this line "for (PackageInfo pkg : apps) {"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PackageInfo.requestedPermissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) return you an Array of String type not String so you will need to change your code as :

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for(PackageInfo pack : packages)
{
   PackageInfo permissionInfo = null;  
    permissionInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pack.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    if(permissionInfo != null){  
         String[] permissions = permissionInfo.requestedPermissions;
          //YOUR CODE HERE
      }
}
```

Comment: pkg.requestedPermissions return a String, not String[]

Comment: this is a screenshot of my logcat https://www.dropbox.com/s/nyemvenuuhg558y/capture.png

Comment: @HCarrasko - Did this really solve your problem?  If yes, please tidy up your comments.  If no, please update your question .... and don't use dropbox links, 'cos they break, like the one above has!

Comment: yes, I've solve this problem and in 7 years I not use dropbox to share files any more. If you want the solution, my answer is I don't remember how I solve this. think bro 7 years!! so sorry but this question can give you some orientation